# dpkg-buildpackage Unmet build dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

I wanted to build Corrade (https://github.com/mosra/corrade), but when I run it according to documentation, it fails when I call

```
dpkg-buildpackage
```

The error I get: `dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: cmake (>= 3.1)`

But when I run `cmake --version`, I get

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

How do I debug this issue? I have no clue where to even start with it.

cmake was installed via pip3 (another framework I use needs cmake >= 3.11, and that compiled fine)

Comment: "cmake was installed via pip3" - It seems that dpkg wants `cmake` to be installed by him.

Comment: If I call `dpkg-buildpackage -d` it works and builds the debs just fine. I just don't understand this

Comment: When check *dependencies*, dpkg checks them by **dpkg packages**. Because you doesn't install such *package* for `cmake`, dpkg reports of its absence. When run with `-d` option, `dpkg-buildpackage` doesn't check dependencies. When it is time to build the package, it runs `cmake`. As you have given executable in the PATH, it is called - no errors.